# How to update collection after user logs in/logs of

Tags: xamarin

I am in my  MyArticlesBrowserViewModel  loading data for the last three displayed articles of course depending on user. Once the user signs of then i call Clean() method and clean _lastOpenedArticles but once the different user logs back on the collection is accurate to his seen articles however i get a picture of the article from the previous user. I think i need some sort of update or refresh do you have some idea?

```
    class MyArticlesBrowserViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData> LastThreeArticles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ArticleDetailData>();

      public MyArticlesBrowserViewModel()
                : base()
            {

                var articlesApiResponse = await AVAT.App.ApiFactory.GetBestSellerArticlesAsync();
                var allArticles = articlesApiResponse.Match(articles => articles.ToList(), _ => new List<Article>());

                FillArticles(allArticles);


                if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn || LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedOffline)
                {

                    ShowLastListened();

                }

            }

      public static void Clean()
            {
                _lastOpenedArticles = null;
                _lastSeenArticles = null;
                _allDownloadedArticles = null;

            }
     void ShowLastListened()
            {
                var lastOpenedArticle = LangUpDataSaverLoader.DeserializeLastLoadedArticle();
                lastOpenedArticle.Reverse();
               _lastOpenedArticles = lastOpenedArticle;

                if (_lastOpenedArticles != null && _lastOpenedArticles.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var article in _lastOpenedArticles.Take(3))
                    {
                        var filename = string.Format(SharedConstants.ArticleImageUrl, SharedConstants.ApiBaseUri, article.Id);
                        var newCell = new ArticleDetailData()
                        {
                            Author = article.Author,
                            Description = article.Description,
                            Body = article.Description,
                            Section = article.Category,
                            BackgroundImage = filename,
                            Id = article.Id,
                            Subtitle = article.Description,
                            Title = article.NameCz,
                            WhenDay = article.DateCreate.Day.ToString() + " / ",
                            WhenMonth = article.DateCreate.Month.ToString() + " / ",
                            WhenYear = article.DateCreate.Year.ToString(),
                            FullDate = article.DateCreate.ToLongDateString(),
                            NumberOfWords = article.NumberOfWords,
                            AmountOfGrammarDescription = article.AmountOfGrammarDescription,
                            ArticleLength = article.ArticleLength,
                            Price = article.Price,
                            IsSubmitted = article.IsSubmitted,
                            BestSellerRating = article.BestSellerRating,
                        };
                        LastThreeArticles.Add(newCell);
                    }
                }
            }

    Binding
     public ArticleBrowser()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel();
                if (BindingContext is MyArticlesBrowserViewModel)
                {
                    var context = new MyArticlesBrowserViewModel();
                    context.LoadData();
                    bestSellers.ItemsSource = context.ListOfBestSellers;
                    lastThreeArticlesCarouselView.ItemsSource = null;
                    lastThreeArticlesCarouselView.ItemsSource = context.LastThreeArticles;

                }

                }


    Logging off user

     public static void LogUserOff()
            {
                _loggedUser = null;
                LoggedIn = false;
                _loggedUserDetail = null;
                MyArticlesBrowserViewModel.Clean();
                LangUpStorage.CleanStorage();
                LangUpUserCredentials.DeleteExistingCredentials();
                LoggingFinished?.Invoke();
            }
   }
XAML
 <local:ExtendedCarouselViewControl x:Name="lastThreeArticlesCarouselView"
                    Grid.Row ="1"
                    HeightRequest="250" 
                    ShowIndicators="True"
                    Margin="0"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    IndicatorsTintColor="{ DynamicResource TranslucidBlack }"
                    CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }"
                    ItemsSource="{ Binding LastThreeArticles, Mode=TwoWay }">
                        <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:AvatArticlesBrowserHeaderItemTemplate />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:ExtendedCarouselViewControl>

    Template
     <ContentView.Content>
            <Grid 
                Margin="0,0,0,40">

                <!-- ARTICLE IMAGE -->
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    Aspect="AspectFill" 
                    Source="{ Binding BackgroundImage }" >
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="ImageTapped"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>


                    <!--PLAY BUTTON-->
                <Button
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="60"
                        HeightRequest="60"
                        CornerRadius="30"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="30"
                        BorderWidth="2"
                        BackgroundColor="#22000000"
                        Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.AudioPlay }"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }"
                        FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                        BorderColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }"
                        Padding="5,0,0,0" 
                        Clicked= "OnPlayButtonClicked"/>

                <!-- DATA -->
                <Grid
                    Padding="20,0,20,5"
                    RowSpacing="0"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    grial:Effects.ApplyIOSSafeAreaAsPadding="Left,Right">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- Date -->
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="{ Binding When }"
                        FontSize="12"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }" />

                    <!-- Title -->
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{ Binding Title }"
                        FontSize="26"
                        Style="{ StaticResource LabelBoldStyle }"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }" />

                    <!-- Category -->
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Text="{ Binding Section }"
                        FontSize="14"
                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }" />
                </Grid>


            </Grid>


</ContentView.Content>
```

Comment: clear the cache - https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Advanced-Usage#all-images

Comment: Have you checked that the BackgroundImage(filename) updated after the user log in?

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT seems that it only adds new picture but the old stays there, so it doesnt update

Comment: So that's the cause? The image is loading through BackgroundImage(filename) in your xaml while it doesn't update.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT how can i fix that?

Comment: You should update the BackgroundImage when the new user login.